# Im trying to run a webserver in iMac but it doesn't work in port 800

Tags: imac, webserver

Im trying to run a local web server Mongoose on mac, its default settings is listening on port 8080,I want to change it to 800 but it doesn't run mongoose once I changed it to 800. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that 800 < 1024, but 8080 ≥ 1024.

Ports with numbers less than 1024 are *privileged ports* (google that) on Unix like systems, which means that only processes which run as root are allowed to listen to them.

Answer (score 4):

You have to run as `root` to bind to the privileged ports (<1024). You can run Mongoose via `sudo`, but then you will have a web server running as `root`. Not a good idea!

Changing user with `run_as_user` parameter also seems to be unsupported on Mac:

```
Mongoose[22361:507] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(),
    which is not allowed.
```

Why don't you pick a port above 1024 e.g. 8081? Then you can run as unprivileged user.

For troubleshooting you can run Mongoose in Terminal.app like this:

```
sudo /Applications/Mongoose.app/Contents/MacOS/Mongoose
```

Comment: @Carsten sorry, you reply came in while I was typing my reply in...

Comment: Im trying to force it in 800 because I'm doing a mac version of an existing windows app. It also acts as a local web server running on port 800. It also uses Mongoose. Well I think I'll have to look for a workaround for this.

Comment: Happens to me all the time, also you give additional information on the specific web server, of which I have never heard.